# firefox extension call to addon function from content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i want to run addon function[main.js] from content script .i read firefox docs but it's not working for me.this is the official docs about communication between scripts https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port

this is my main.js code

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://mydomain/x.html",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("listen.js")
});

self.port.on("myAddonMessage", function(myAddonMessagePayload) {
  console.log("working");
});
```

this is my listen.js content script

```
var myContentScriptMessagePayload="hi"; 
self.port.emit("myContentScriptMessage", myContentScriptMessagePayload);
```

actually i expect console.log("working"); this output .but it's not working .can some one help me i'm really confused here..i actually want to call main.js function from listen.js .

Answer (score 2):

`main.js` doesn't have a `self.port`, content-scripts do. In `main.js` you instead need to use port with whatever initiated the content-script. E.g. the [`PageMod` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Communicating_With_Content_Scripts) has more.

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://mydomain/x.html",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("listen.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on("myAddonMessage", function(myAddonMessagePayload) {
      console.log("working");
    });
  }
});
```